# Wordpress 5.3 get only gallery from post

Tags: wordpress, gallery

Is it possible to get only the gallery-img-ids from a post in `wordpress` 5.3 ?

```
get_post_gallery_images()

and

get_post_gallery()
```

returns an   empty array

Comment: do you mean in WordPress 5.3 **Gutenberg**?

Comment: yes! -> WordPress 5.3 Gutenberg

Comment: Gallery system has changed since Gutenberg you can't parse anymore the ID's displayed in shortcode but the full rendered block as suggested in this answer : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325431/136456